# Issue when iphone takes place the Landscape Orientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am using the delegate method  for auto rotation in iphone application.

```
    -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{

    if(interfaceOrientation  == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ){
            [UIView beginAnimations:@"View Flip" context:nil];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2f];
            [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
            self..view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
            self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0,0,320,460);
            [UIView commitAnimations];
            self.navigationBar.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);


        }else if(interfaceOrientation  == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){

            [UIView beginAnimations:@"View Flip" context:nil];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2f];
            [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
            CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3.14159/2);
            self.view.transform = transform;
            CGRect contentRect = CGRectMake(10, -10, 480, 300);
            self.view.bounds = contentRect;
            [UIView commitAnimations];

            self.navigationBar.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 32);

        }else if(interfaceOrientation  == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft){
            //navigationController.navigationBar.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 34);
            [UIView beginAnimations:@"View Flip" context:nil];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2f];
            [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
            CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-3.14159/2);
            self.view.transform = transform;
            CGRect contentRect = CGRectMake(-10, -10, 480, 300);
            self.view.bounds = contentRect;
            [UIView commitAnimations];

            self.navigationBar.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 32);
        }else if(interfaceOrientation  == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown ){
               return NO;
        }
        return YES;
    }
```

It is working fine  on iphone OS3 but on iphone OS4, when rotating to landscape mode, the interface displays incorrectly

[image: Landscape]

When rotating back to portrait mode the interfaces compresses....
[image: Portrait]

Please suggest me any suggestion how I resolve it ??

Thanks
Deepika

Comment: I don't know if this is the problem but you've got a lot of hardcoded numbers in there - you should try to use computed values whenever you can i.e. instead of 320 you should use self.view.frame.size.width;

Answer (score 0):

CGRect contentRect = CGRectMake(-10, -10, 480, 300);
            self.view.bounds = contentRect;

why you giving -10,-10 ? any specific reason .This is completely due to frame mismatching. Just change that frame and check it.

Comment: I set (-10 ,-10) for just poisoning of view on screen....I m using ipod(Version 3.1.3)..on this iPod it is working fine...but on iPhone 4.0,it is not working.

Comment: iOS4 having a lot of issue.So code working fine in 3.0 series doesn't mean must work fine for iOS4. i think this is frame maintaining issue. Just change the frame and also change the background color of all the subviews than you exact frame of each view. Try once ....